# WordPress AJAX Login Screen

Tags: ajax, login, front-end, wp-login-form

In recent versions of WordPress, when you have been logged in to the dashboard a while with the page still open, WordPress times out your session and opens a login box. This box appears in a little popup and allows you to login without having to refresh the page. Does anyone know if there is a built in way to utilize this popup in the frontend?

I have a link that requires a user to be logged in in order for it to have any action. When a user is not logged in, I want a popup login form to assist with this and I'm hoping there is an easy way already so I don't need to follow some of these older tutorials and do everything manually because that sometimes makes it harder to maintain compatibility with future versions.

Thanks for any advice offered!

Comment: Why dont you use the plugin??? https://wordpress.org/plugins/login-with-ajax/

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to use a plug-in like [Lightbox Plus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/lightbox-plus/) to power your link. Clicking the link would load your standard login form inside a lightbox. You could then automatically redirect to the same page so that, once logged in, users can leave a comment.

Basically, you'd dynamically build your link to be something link this:

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fyoursite.com%2Fpostname" rel="lightbox[login-form]" itle="Please login to comment">Login to Comment</a>
```

This would load the login form in a lightbox and set it to redirect to the post upon successful authentication. This might be all you need, but I haven't tested it ... so give it a try and, if needed, add some other scripts to reload the page upon successful login.